# How compile the FreeTDS with OpenSSL for Win32?

Tags: cmake, openssl, freetds

Please explain in detail (**step by step**) how to compile **FreeTDS** with **OpenSSL** for **Win32**?

I tried it like this:

1. Download and extract freetds-1.3.18.tar.gz from https://www.freetds.org/
2. Run CMake => Configure, Generate, Open Project.
3. In Visual Studio 2019 build ALL_BUILD project (Debug & Release). More than 100 warnings.
4. The Debug and Release folders are empty.

**P.S.**

OpenSSL - installed => c:/program files(x86)/openssl-win32

**Details:**

CMake

Source code: c:/code/freetds-1.3.18

Where to build binaries: c:/code/freetdsbin

Visual Studio 16 2019

Win32

Use default native compilers

```
CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES   Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX        C:/Program Files (x86)/FreeTDS
ENABLE_EXTRA_CHECKS     Not checked
ENABLE_KRB5         Not checked
ENABLE_ODBC_MARS        Checked
ENABLE_ODBC_WIDE        Checked
GPERF               GPERF-NOTFOUND
LIB_EAY_DEBUG           LIB_EAY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
LIB_EAY_RELEASE         LIB_EAY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND
SSL_EAY_DEBUG           SSL_EAY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
SSL_EAY_RELEASE         SSL_EAY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND
WITH_OPENSSL            Checked

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  cmake_minimum_required() should be called prior to this top-level project()
  call.  Please see the cmake-commands(7) manual for usage documentation of
  both commands.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 6.1.7601.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30148.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30148.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 

Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 

Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Could NOT find Perl (missing: PERL_EXECUTABLE) 
Looking for arpa/inet.h
Looking for arpa/inet.h - not found
Looking for com_err.h
Looking for com_err.h - not found
Looking for dirent.h
Looking for dirent.h - not found
Looking for errno.h
Looking for errno.h - found
Looking for getopt.h
Looking for getopt.h - not found
Looking for inttypes.h
Looking for inttypes.h - found
Looking for langinfo.h
Looking for langinfo.h - not found
Looking for libgen.h
Looking for libgen.h - not found
Looking for limits.h
Looking for limits.h - found
Looking for locale.h
Looking for locale.h - found
Looking for malloc.h
Looking for malloc.h - found
Looking for netdb.h
Looking for netdb.h - not found
Looking for netinet/in.h
Looking for netinet/in.h - not found
Looking for netinet/tcp.h
Looking for netinet/tcp.h - not found
Looking for paths.h
Looking for paths.h - not found
Looking for poll.h
Looking for poll.h - not found
Looking for roken.h
Looking for roken.h - not found
Looking for signal.h
Looking for signal.h - found
Looking for sql.h
Looking for sql.h - not found
Looking for sqlext.h
Looking for sqlext.h - not found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Looking for stdlib.h
Looking for stdlib.h - found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for string.h
Looking for string.h - found
Looking for strings.h
Looking for strings.h - not found
Looking for sys/eventfd.h
Looking for sys/eventfd.h - not found
Looking for sys/ioctl.h
Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
Looking for sys/param.h
Looking for sys/param.h - not found
Looking for sys/resource.h
Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
Looking for sys/select.h
Looking for sys/select.h - not found
Looking for sys/socket.h
Looking for sys/socket.h - not found
Looking for sys/stat.h
Looking for sys/stat.h - found
Looking for sys/time.h
Looking for sys/time.h - not found
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for sys/wait.h
Looking for sys/wait.h - not found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
Looking for fcntl.h
Looking for fcntl.h - found
Looking for wchar.h
Looking for wchar.h - found
Looking for windows.h
Looking for windows.h - found
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR 

(missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
Looking for pthread_create in pthread
Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Looking for include files windows.h, sql.h
Looking for include files windows.h, sql.h - found
Looking for 3 include files windows.h, ..., sqlext.h
Looking for 3 include files windows.h, ..., sqlext.h - found
Looking for 3 include files windows.h, ..., odbcss.h
Looking for 3 include files windows.h, ..., odbcss.h - found
Check size of char
Check size of char - done
Check size of double
Check size of double - done
Check size of float
Check size of float - done
Check size of int
Check size of int - done
Check size of short
Check size of short - done
Check size of long
Check size of long - done
Check size of long double
Check size of long double - done
Check size of long long
Check size of long long - done
Check size of SQLWCHAR
Check size of SQLWCHAR - done
Check size of void *
Check size of void * - done
Check size of wchar_t
Check size of wchar_t - done
Check size of __int64
Check size of __int64 - done
Check size of SQLLEN
Check size of SQLLEN - done
Check size of SQLROWOFFSET
Check size of SQLROWOFFSET - done
Check size of SQLROWSETSIZE
Check size of SQLROWSETSIZE - done
Check size of SQLSETPOSIROW
Check size of SQLSETPOSIROW - done
Checking prototype SQLColAttribute for TDS_SQLCOLATTRIBUTE_SQLLEN
Checking prototype SQLColAttribute for TDS_SQLCOLATTRIBUTE_SQLLEN - True
Checking prototype SQLParamOptions for TDS_SQLPARAMOPTIONS_SQLLEN
Checking prototype SQLParamOptions for TDS_SQLPARAMOPTIONS_SQLLEN - True
Looking for asprintf
Looking for asprintf - not found
Looking for vasprintf
Looking for vasprintf - not found
Looking for strtok_r
Looking for strtok_r - not found
Looking for strtok_s
Looking for strtok_s - found
Looking for readpassphrase
Looking for readpassphrase - not found
Looking for strlcpy
Looking for strlcpy - not found
Looking for strlcat
Looking for strlcat - not found
Looking for basename
Looking for basename - not found
Looking for getopt
Looking for getopt - not found
Looking for strsep
Looking for strsep - not found
Looking for vsnprintf
Looking for vsnprintf - not found
Looking for _vsnprintf
Looking for _vsnprintf - not found
Looking for snprintf
Looking for snprintf - not found
Looking for _snprintf
Looking for _snprintf - not found
Looking for _vscprintf
Looking for _vscprintf - not found
Looking for gettimeofday
Looking for gettimeofday - not found
Looking for nl_langinfo
Looking for nl_langinfo - not found
Looking for locale_charset
Looking for locale_charset - not found
Looking for setenv
Looking for setenv - not found
Looking for putenv
Looking for putenv - found
Looking for getuid
Looking for getuid - not found
Looking for getpwuid
Looking for getpwuid - not found
Looking for getpwuid_r
Looking for getpwuid_r - not found
Looking for fstat
Looking for fstat - found
Looking for alarm
Looking for alarm - not found
Looking for fork
Looking for fork - not found
Looking for gethrtime
Looking for gethrtime - not found
Looking for localtime_r
Looking for localtime_r - not found
Looking for setitimer
Looking for setitimer - not found
Looking for _fseeki64
Looking for _fseeki64 - found
Looking for _ftelli64
Looking for _ftelli64 - found
Looking for setrlimit
Looking for setrlimit - not found
Looking for inet_ntoa_r
Looking for inet_ntoa_r - not found
Looking for getipnodebyaddr
Looking for getipnodebyaddr - not found
Looking for getipnodebyname
Looking for getipnodebyname - not found
Looking for inet_ntop
Looking for inet_ntop - not found
Looking for gethostname
Looking for gethostname - not found
Looking for poll
Looking for poll - not found
Looking for socketpair
Looking for socketpair - not found
Looking for clock_gettime
Looking for clock_gettime - not found
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - not found
Looking for pthread_cond_timedwait
Looking for pthread_cond_timedwait - not found
Looking for pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np
Looking for pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np - not found
Looking for pthread_condattr_setclock
Looking for pthread_condattr_setclock - not found
Looking for _lock_file
Looking for _lock_file - found
Looking for _unlock_file
Looking for _unlock_file - found
Looking for usleep
Looking for usleep - not found
Looking for nanosleep
Looking for nanosleep - not found
Looking for readdir_r
Looking for readdir_r - not found
Looking for eventfd
Looking for eventfd - not found
Looking for daemon
Looking for daemon - not found
Looking for system
Looking for system - found
Looking for asprintf
Looking for asprintf - not found
Looking for vasprintf
Looking for vasprintf - not found
Looking for vsnprintf
Looking for vsnprintf - found
Looking for _vsnprintf
Looking for _vsnprintf - found
Looking for snprintf
Looking for snprintf - found
Looking for _snprintf
Looking for _snprintf - found
Looking for _vscprintf
Looking for _vscprintf - found
Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE
Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE - Failed
Looking for readline in readline
Looking for readline in readline - not found
Looking for _vsnwprintf_s in legacy_stdio_definitions
Looking for _vsnwprintf_s in legacy_stdio_definitions - found
Configuring done (331.8s)
Generating done (4.6s)
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why not just run `cmake --build <build_dir>` instead of building from visual studio?

Comment: interestingly, as far as I can see, [the build docs](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/build.html) don't even seem to mention CMake. I suppose they're outdated? But in the CMakeLists.txt at line 5, there's `option(WITH_OPENSSL        "Link in OpenSSL if found" ON)` so I suppose you shouldn't need to do anything in particular. Do you have OpenSSL installed? Do you get an errors during the configuration process?

Comment: Notice how in your CMake configure output it says "_Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL Lite was installed. And I needed OpenSSL Full.